# How to debug: Change from div to form element in React. No response

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I try to change from `div` to `form` element (to use the `type="submit"`) in the react render but there's no response. It shows `http://localhost:3000/?` FYI, `div` is working fine. The code is as below:

```
<div className="SearchBar">
 <input placeholder="Enter A Song, Album, or Artist" onChange={this.handleTermChange} />
 <a onClick={this.handleSearch}>SEARCH</a>
</div>

===

<form className="SearchBar" onSubmit={this.handleSearch}>
 <input placeholder="Enter A Song, Album, or Artist"  onChange={this.handleTermChange} />
 <button type="submit">SEARCH</button>
</form>
```

The Github repo is [here](https://github.com/kengkeelim/jamming/blob/master/src/Components/SearchBar/SearchBar.js).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your submit is giving refresh on the screen.

Use an e.preventDefault () at the beginning of your function its handleSearch function